# How to derive the following equation in DFT?

Tags: density-functional-theory

Recently, I have read a paper (J.Chem.Phys,99,1993 by Kais and others: download [here](http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/kais1993.pdf)) which uses Harmonium model to inverse Kohn-Sham equation and obtain exchange-correlation potential. Without going into extra details, pay attention to the beginning of section 3, where the authors refer eq 16:
$$
E=2\epsilon_{ks}-\int \rho v_H[\rho]dr-\int \rho v_{xc}[\rho]dr+E_{xc}[\rho] \tag{16}
$$

and replacing eq 17:
$$
v_{xc}[\rho]=\epsilon_{ks}-v_{ext}(r)-2v_H[\rho]-v_{KE}[\rho] \tag{17}
$$
in it, to obtain eq 24:
$$
E=E_{ext}+E_{KE}+2E_H+E_{xc} \tag{24}
$$
It seems extremely simple, but I can't obtain eq 24 and it's ridiculous! Taking advantage of eq 10:
$$
v_H[\rho(r)]=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac {\rho(r')}{\lvert r-r' \rvert} dr' \tag{10}
$$
and eq 27:
$$
E_H[\rho]=\frac{1}{2} \int \rho v_H[\rho]dr \tag{27}
$$

I obtain eq 24 plus an $\epsilon_{ks}$, and I can't understand how they can eliminate $\epsilon$s! I think that I'm ignoring some simple point. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where that constant is important. I suspect that your extra $\epsilon_{s}$ comes from neglecting the fact that the integral of the density should be $2$.

The main relation they are using is the correction for the Kohn-Sham (KS) eigenvalue sum:
$$ E = E_{s} +(U + E_{xc} - \langle v_{H} + v_{xc} \rangle), \tag{1} $$
where the KS eigenvalue sum and Hartree energy
$$ E_{s} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\epsilon_{s,i}, \quad \quad U = \frac{1}{2}\int d^{3}r\int d^{3}r' \frac{n(\textbf{r})n(\textbf{r'})}{\vert \textbf{r} - \textbf{r'}\vert}. \tag{2}$$
Here $\langle v_{H} \rangle = 2U$ and $\langle v_{xc}\rangle$ are the expectaton value of the Hartree and exchange-correlation potentials and $E_{xc}$ is the full XC energy (which is not equal to the expectation value of the XC potential).

For two-electrons with a spin-singlet groundstate:
$$ E = 2\epsilon_{s} +(U + E_{xc} - \langle v_{H} + v_{xc} \rangle). \tag{3} $$
What the authors are doing is using the KS equation for the only orbital to determine an expression for the eigenvalue. Once you have the density, $n(\textbf{r}) = 2\vert \phi(\textbf{r})\vert^{2}$, then you immediately have an expression for the eigenvalue:
$$ \left\{\frac{1}{2}\nabla^{2} + v(\textbf{r}) + v_{H}(\textbf{r}) + v_{xc}(\textbf{r})\right\}\sqrt{\frac{n(\textbf{r})}{2}} = \epsilon_{s} \sqrt{\frac{n(\textbf{r})}{2}}, \tag{4} $$
once we compute the derivatives and divide through by $\sqrt{n(\textbf{r})/2}$,
$$ \frac{1}{8}\frac{\vert \nabla n(\textbf{r})\vert^{2}}{n(\textbf{r})^{2}}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\nabla^{2}n(\textbf{r})}{n(\textbf{r})} + v_{H}(\textbf{r}) + v_{xc}(\textbf{r}) = \epsilon_{s}, \tag{5}$$
and if we multiply by the density and integrate:
$$ \frac{1}{8}\int d^{3}r \, \frac{\vert \nabla n(\textbf{r})\vert^{2}}{n(\textbf{r})} + \langle v \rangle + \langle v_{H} \rangle + \langle v_{xc} \rangle = 2\epsilon_{s}. \tag{6}$$

The integral with the laplacian vanishes if the density is finite (vanishes sufficiently fast at infinity). The left-most remaining term with the single gradient squared is a standard quantity: the [Von-Weizacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Weizs%C3%A4cker_kinetic_energy_functional) expression for the kinetic energy, but for this case it is exactly the kinetic energy of the KS system, $T_{s}$ (only for two-electrons with a singlet ground-state).

Combining the above equation with first equation:
$$ E = T_{s} + \langle v \rangle + U + E_{xc}, \tag{7} $$
I am using more modern notation, but this is equivalent to their Eq. (24):

$$ E = E_{KE} + E_{ext}  + 2E_{H} + E_{xc}. \tag{8}  $$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I didn't understand why you obtained eq 16 again? it's just equivalent of eq (7.2.10) of Density-Functional Theory of Atoms and Molecules book by Parr&Yang. Also in the paper, authors say "we obtain eq 24 by simply recasting 16 using 17", so to be honest I didn't get your mean. Please explain more.

Comment: My Eq. (1) can be derived by playing around with the definitions of the energies in DFT. For the case of Hooke's atom we only have a single Kohn-Sham orbital that is doubly-occupied, so the energy of the KS system is just twice the single orbital energy (which is how I get from Eq. 1 to Eq. 3).  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks I see, but with knowing this point, when I replace $v_{xc}$ of eq 16 by its definition of eq 17 and then integrate, $\epsilon$ comes out of the integral because it's a constant, so finally I reach $2\epsilon-\epsilon$ which leaves us with an extra $\epsilon$ which doesn't exit in eq 24!

Comment: I am not quite sure I follow your last comment. If you plug in your Eq (17)  to Eq (16) you will have a constant multiplied by an integral involving the density, which must integrate to 2, so you will have the constant cancel as well.

Comment: Oh! I think, as you pointed, integration over density is equal to 2, not 1, namely we have: $\int \rho \epsilon dr=2\epsilon$ not $1\epsilon$. right?

Comment: Yes, which is what I started my answer with :)

Comment: yeah, you're right. Sorry, I think your extra explanations for obtaining equations didn't let me understand your main point. However, thanks a lot.